# How to schedule/queue a task based on saved mongodb document data [NodeJS]

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, task-queue

I want to have a function in my server which a user can create a 'jobScan' from an API route for example '/create-scan-job which basically on the creation of a scanJob it will be saved in the mongodb database with a 'scanDueDate' which will be used to queue a task that will change the status of the scan to 'completed' on the dueDate that was inputted by the user.

How can I build something like this? I have no problem in saving the data in the database but how do I 'queue' it to fire on the dueDate that was given as input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [agenda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda) or [bull](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull) packages.

1. Agenda saves jobs in MongoDB database
2. Bull saves jobs in Redis.

Both support cron jobs.

Comment: I saw that in order to have bull, I need to have a running redis server. Is there a way to achieve this in one local server running?

Comment: Yes bull runs on a different port. Port# 6379.

Comment: Can you link me a source on how to set it up with nodejs? meaning the redis server as I did not find the example in the bull documentation. thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which OS are u using?

Comment: MacOS and sorry for kind of asking again but I am new to this, so redis and nodejs running each it’s own server?

Comment: Yes. They will have their own software servers.

Answer (score 0):

Agenda is using MongoDB for queue scheduling, but it's a bit unstable, [as you may see on the issues page](https://github.com/agenda/agenda/issues). And you may also use [Bree](https://jobscheduler.net) as well, but it does store job queue in-memory.

As for the [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) or [BullMQ](https://github.com/taskforcesh/bullmq), that have been notified here, truly it does use Redis, as queue storage. But its docs descriptions don't seem full. And as I remember, Redis doesn't support Windows out-of-the-box. So if you want to run it locally, I highly recommend you use [the Redis Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis) for that.

Also, don't forget about GUI, for task-queues. You could use:

- Agendash, (with Agenda) which allows to create jobs manually from the interface.
- Bull-board (with Bull or BullMQ) which provides only read-only data about tasks.